# He Was Victorious (a short riddle)

Tags: riddle, rhyme, wordplay, poetry

*He was victorious, say you, in a foreign tongue.

He was almost there, he's a ring in the skin;

A half-fisted stove; a snake by the nines.

Christmas Eve now holds their endless odd gin.*

---

**What is this poem about?**

---

*Hint/Clarification:*

> This isn't a "Who/what am I?" riddle (meaning this riddle does not describe a singular entity).

Comment: *Great* puzzle, Bailey!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

What is this poem about?

> counting from 1 to 8

He was victorious,

> he won > ONE

say you, in a foreign tongue.

> "you" in French is "tu" > TWO

He was almost there,

> "almost" means make an anagram of "there" > THREE

he's a ring in the skin

> a ring is O, skin is FUR > FOUR

A half-fisted stove;

> half of fisted is "fis"; stove is to be read as a direction: "s" to "ve" meaning take "fis" and change the "s" to "ve" > FIVE

a snake by the nines.

> a snake is S, nine is IX > SIX

Christmas Eve now holds

> "holds" means "contains" > Christma**s Eve n**ow > SEVEN

their endless odd gin

> "their" endless is "thei"; odd means to make an anagram; "gin" again is interpreted as a direction - "G in", meaning to put a G into "eiht" > EIGHT

Comment: *Almost* perfect; I'm sure you realize that five and eight aren't quite right. I experimented with some very difficult wordplay for those. Take half of fisted, then what's left in that clue? Try interpreting it as if it wasn't a word and see what you can find.

Comment: HA!  On the old Atlantic Monthly message board we called this a "gestalt" clue.

Comment: "gin" = "G in": you put a G in to the "eiht" you've got. Nice riddle btw @BaileyM - just the sort of thing I'd write :-) (And I wrote this comment before I even saw the similar "s to ve" clue! Edit: *fantastic* riddle.)

Comment: This answer is still a bit overshadowed by the Prince Albert answer that somehow makes sense of what I fully intended to be gibberish, but it's still correct (and now completely so). Well done! :)

Comment: This was very clever! Nicely done @dennisdeems. May I ask, what was the breakthrough moment/clue?

Comment: Thanks!  The breakthrough clue was the word "holds".  If this were a crossword, that would be the first thing to jump out at me.  Then I started looking for a context for that result.

Comment: their endless odd gin -> endless : infinite ? That would make a ∞, a layed 8

Comment: Thanks for solving this! Now that people see it's not just a typical "What am I?" riddle, the upvotes are flowing in. :D

Comment: @BaileyM yay, I finally broke 2k!  :D

Comment: Whoooah! A puzzle of a completely different kind to what I thought. Great work, top marks.

Comment: This is a great example of making an interesting puzzle from unlikely material.

Answer (score 12):

It's about

> [Prince Albert](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albert,_Prince_Consort)

Because

He was victorious, say you,

> He married Queen Victoria

in a foreign tongue.

> His native language was German

He was almost there, he's a ring in the skin;

> [I'm going to let Wikipedia answer this one.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prince_Albert_(genital_piercing)) <----------- Link NSFW - Not Safe For Work.

A half-fisted stove;

> [Rifle Brigade (Prince Consort's Own)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rifle_Brigade_(Prince_Consort%27s_Own)) wore "stovepipe shakoes"

a snake

> The engagement ring which Albert gave to Victoria was in the shape of a snake

by the nines.

> nine children

Christmas Eve now holds their

> [Many Christmas traditions come from Victoria and Albert.](http://news.bbc.co.uk/local/berkshire/hi/people_and_places/history/newsid_9286000/9286971.stm)

endless odd gin.

> 'gin' in the playing cards sense, because he liked playing Patience, which seems to go on forever.

Comment: When you unknowingly click the wikipedia link in work....

Comment: @alexmc Sorry. I've marked it NSFW.

Comment: This...is a very good answer to the riddle. My intended answer is not nearly this concrete -- the 'wordplay' tag is rather crucial to solving it. Still, a big ol' +1 for making sense out of nonsense, as it were!